# How to encode or input a Graph adjacency matrix to a LSTM recurrent neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, lstm

> I am working on link prediction in social network graphs project. I created an adjacency matrix for all nodes at a given timestamp(t). How to feed this adjacency matrix to an LSTM to predict the connections at (t+1) timestamp. Below is the code snippet for adjacency matrix.

```
filter_df=rslt_df[['Node_Start','Node_End']]
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(filter_df, 'Node_Start', 'Node_End')
A=nx.adjacency_matrix(G)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can flatten the adjacency matrix and reshape it into a vector to pass it to your LSTM model. So let's say if your matrix has shape (6,6), you can change it to (1, 36) to be used as input features to LSTM.

You can do so using

`A.toarray().reshape(1, -1)`

1 in `reshape(1, -1)` makes the first dimension to be 1 and second dimension is automatically calculated as per the number of elements in the adjacency matrix and hence we put -1.